# Inversão de Array

Tags: c

Quero inverter um array, exemplo:

```
void exercicio5()
{
    float array[6] = {10.1, 11.2, 12.3, 127.0, 512.17, -2.5};
    float inverso[6];
    int cont, x = 6;
    for (cont = 0; cont < 6; cont++)
    {
        x--;
        inverso[x] = array[cont];
        printf(" %.2f \n ", inverso[x]);
    }
}
```

eu fiz assim so que ele nao ta invertendo ele apenas mostra os valores do "array" e nao os inverte, como posso resolver este problema?

Answer (score 3):

Invertendo estava, mas você estava invertendo a impressão também.
Só trocar o lado das variáveis já resolve:

```
void exercicio5()
{
    float array[6] = { 10.1, 11.2, 12.3, 127.0, 512.17, -2.5 };
    float inverso[6];
    int cont, x = 6;
    for (cont = 0; cont < 6; cont++)
    {
        x--;
        inverso[cont] = array[x];
        printf(" %.2f \n ", inverso[cont]);
    }
}
```

Agora, dá pra simplificar se quiser:

```
void exercicio5()
{
    int   tamanho = 6;
    float array[] = { 10.1, 11.2, 12.3, 127.0, 512.17, -2.5 };
    float inverso[tamanho];

    for ( int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++ )
    {
        inverso[i] = array[tamanho - i - 1];
        printf( "%.2f \n", inverso[i] );
    }
}
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/rvbSmM)**.

Se por um acaso seu compilador não for C99 (ou achar melhor não inventar muita "moda" no exercício), tire o `int` do `for`:

```
    int i;

    for ( i = 0; i < tamanho; i++ )
```

Comment: o que faz "sizeof(array)" ? qual sua funcao e aplicacao?

Comment: como é exercicio, melhor nao complicar. Pus um demo no IDEONE na resposta, se quiser testar. Mas mais importante do que funcionar, é você entender como foi resolvido. Pegou a idéia? A primeira versão é a mesma que a sua, só troquei o lado das variáveis para imprimir na ordem certa. Na segunda versão, em vez de usar outra variável, fizemos um cálculo simples pra ir de 5 a zero

Comment: @AGenaro só de curiosidade, um exemplo do uso do sizeof: http://ideone.com/i5AnIr (mas pra exercício acho melhor não inventar muita moda) - basicamente estamos pegando o tamanho ocupado pelo array, e dividindo pelo tamanho que um float ocupa. Isso retorna o número de floats nno array. Se você acrescentar ou tirar algum, continua funcionando, sem ter que mexer no resto do código.